# Small Demo application on DeferredResult In spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi I just Need an application on DeferredResult in Spring MVC which clear it's working.

Comment: This is not coding service?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier when you understand the concept of `DeferredResult`: 
Your controller is eventually a function executed by the servlet container (for that matter, let's assume that the server container is Tomcat) worker thread. Your service flow start with Tomcat and ends with Tomcat. Tomcat gets the request from the client, holds the connection, and eventually returns a response to the client. Your code (controller or servlet) is somewhere in the middle.

Consider this flow:

1. Tomcat get client request.
2. Tomcat executes your controller.
3. Release Tomcat thread but keep the client connection (don't return response) and run heavy processing on different thread.
4. When your heavy processing complete, update Tomcat with its response and return it to the client (by Tomcat).

Because the servlet (your code) and the servlet container (Tomcat) are different entities, then to allow this flow (releasing tomcat thread but keep the client connection) we need to have this support in [their contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html), the package `javax.servlet`, which introduced in [Servlet 3.0](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm) . Spring MVC use this new Servlet 3.0 capability when the return value of the controller is `DeferredResult` (BTW, also `Callable`). `DeferredResult` is a class designed by Spring to allow more options (that I will describe) for asynchronous request processing in Spring MVC, and this class just holds the result (as implied by its name) so it means you need some kind of thread that will run you async code. What do you get by using `DeferredResult` as the return value of the controller? `DeferredResult` has built-in callbacks like `onError`, `onTimeout`, and `onCompletion`. It makes error handling very easy.

[Here](https://github.com/elirandav/aviato/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/aviato) you can find a simple working examples I created.

The main part from the github example:

```
@RestController
public class DeferredResultController {
    static ExecutorService threadPool = getThreadPool();
    private Request request = new Request();

    @RequestMapping(value="/deferredResultHelloWorld/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DeferredResult<String> search(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        threadPool.submit(() -> deferredResult.setResult(request.runSleepOnOtherService(name)));
        return deferredResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/14/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-adding-long-polling-to-an-existing-web-application

and the source code is: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/spring-mvc-async

for useful articles see blog post series about spring async support:
https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support